# how to install vacation plugin to roundcube?

Tags: mysql, plugins, postfix-mta, dovecot, roundcube

I try install vacation plugin to roundcube. I puted vacation folder to plugins folder and I added name of folder to array in config file of roundcube. I use virtual users on based mysql database. My postfix works, good and Dovecot with roundcube but I can't open vacation plugin because I receive an error aobut wrong configuration. What I should be added to config file of vacation plugin while postfix with dovecot using? I would like to that every user can to setting own auto reply after successed login to self mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

you need to install dovecot-pigeonhole package, edit the dovecot conf files and install roundcube managesieve plugin.

for reference, you can visit this [link](https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?t=11363) or [this](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-set-up-server-side-email-filtering-with-dovecot-sieve-and-roundcube-on-a-centos-6-vps/)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This looks more like a comment than an answer. The OP says he has roundcube and dovecot. Per your list managesieve is missing. Why not show an example of these together to enable vacation.